# Script bash for unique hostname

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I everyone, I have to make a script for an IT training and have a question. My script allows me to create a user, to delete one or to change the hostname, but the hostame must be unique each time.

I wanted to know, with `bash`, how to do for the hostname to be unique. For example, to have a random number at the end of the hostname but which won’t be repeated again or to have the name of the PC according to the IP but I don’t know how to do.

I don’t know how to do so that on my different computers, the hostname is unique each and to make sure I have no duplicates. I would like to do this, with the unique part of the hostname

```
echo "New pc name"
read "newpcname"

hostnamectl set-hostname $newnamepc

echo "New computer name is $newpcname"
```

Comment: Hint: try using `nslookup $hostname` ; if this succeeds (exit code 0), then the hostname already exists in the network (and you should get the IP of the machine), else it is free.

Comment: Thanks but i have to do the hostname directly in the script. In the best case i like to add randomize number at the end of the hostname but i can't have two times the shame randomize number

Comment: Do you know how to do a test in `bash`? E.g. `if nslookup $hostname >/dev/null ; then echo $hostname exists ; else $hostname is free`? Maybe you should be more specific in your question: should the hostname be unique in the network or should it never have been given to the machine before? For random strings use e.g. `mktemp -u XXX` but an increasing integer as suffix might make more sense for a network.

Comment: Yes i know, sorry if I don't be specific but in english it's hard for me. I have the start of my script i write it above. I'd like to take the ip of the machine and add that to the hostname i write myself. Or juste write an hostname and at the end add a randomize number which can't be duplicated

Comment: Bash provides `$RANDOM` which returns a pseudo-random integer between 0 and 32767 each time it's used. You could also `date '+%N'` to get the nanosecond component of the current timestamp, which is unlikely to repeat often. Either of those could be appended to `$newpcname` to give you a reasonably random hostname.

Comment: Yes thanks i add randnum=$(( RANDOM % 100 )) to my script do you know something to grab the last numbers of my ip and add this to my hostname

Comment: Use `hostname -I` to show your IPs (v4 & v6, no loopback). To show the IP cennected with the current hostname in the network use e.g. `nslookup $HOSTNAME` or `dig $HOSTNAME`. There are many options.